# Generating systhetic data samples by targeting a non-existing special value for a certain colunm in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, data-science

Assume that we have the following DataFrame;

```
    Age   Weight  Gender  Marks
0    10      20       0      5      
1    11      19       1      4
2    15      25       0      2
```

Here, the `Marks` column only have the values: `2`,`4`, and `5`. However I need to have additional data rows whose  `Marks` value will be equal to, as an example `1`. So the final data-set with the synthetically generated rows would be like,

```
    Age   Weight  Gender  Marks
0    10      20       0      5      
1    11      19       1      4
2    15      25       0      2
3     ?       ?       ?      1
4     ?       ?       ?      1
5     ?       ?       ?      1
```

How can we generate such synthetic data while keeping original data characteristics in columns `Age`, `Weight`, `Gender`, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it is better to question why you need that synthetic data. As an example if you are wishing to use the final data-set for classification problem which predicts `Marks` column, then your intention is not suitable at all. Because you are trying to generate some set of columns based on 'Marks' and then you are trying to use those to predict 'Marks'; which will be a very bad idea as the huge over-fitting.

Being said above, if you still need to generate such data-set, a one method will be using a technique like logistic regression. But, it will not be easy as in *typical* logistic regression solutions. The main problem here is loss of columns (i.e. you have one single column `Marks`). What comes to my mind is this procedure: you have 3 more columns `Age`, `Weight` and `Marks`. First you can find the correlations for each these columns against the `Marks` column. Then choose the column with highest correlation with `Marks`, let say it is `Age`. Then predict the values for `Age` by creating a prediction model using only the `Marks` and `Age` columns. Now you have a data-set with `Marks` and `Age` columns. Now get the next highest correlation column and do the same procedure until all remaining columns are used. This will create a bit fair data-set, but I don't think it is a very good solution.

Finally what I mostly prefer on this problem is random generation of data which will be *fair* anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the original data and concat it with the original one, for example:

```py
new_df = pd.concat([df, df.assign(Marks=1)], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Actually, I need the other columns' values to be showing the special characteristics to make the target column's values. Let's take an example. I need other column values which makes the `Marks` value `1`. Assume that  I have a classification model created using the ONLY the "original DataFrame", which predicts the `Marks` value. So, a values of a generated row will be able to predict an very near value equal value to `1` (in this case may be `2` as the predicted value).